# move cursor to next if the row has the same value

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

Table **songs**

```
|COLUMN|
 singer1
 singer1
 singer2
 singer2
```

if my query looks like this,

> select * from songs

The result is:

```
/Result/
singer1
singer1
singer2
singer2
```

my problem is how to display like this

```
/Result/
singer1
singer2
```

How to skip the duplicate value?

Comment: `select distinct column_name from songs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using active record

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('your_column');
$query = $this->db->get('your_table');
```

Other way

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT your_column FROM your_table");
```

To see what your query returned

```
print_r( $query->result_array() );
```

If you want to work using limited resource, then use

`unbuffered_row()`

> This method returns a single result row without prefetching the whole
>   result in memory as `row()` does. If your query has more than one row,
>   it returns the current row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

```
while ($row = $query->unbuffered_row('array'))
{
        echo $row['your_column'].PHP_EOL;
}
```